# Gotchas in JDK 6

Tags: java, java-6, java-5

Are there any gotchas in JDK 6 which did not exist in earlier versions? I am interested in finding out some surprising changes like the following one in the way Timestamp.valueOf() works.

Timestamp.valueOf(), when provided with a timestamp which contains a date or a month with a single digit. eg. 2009-9-20, 2009-9-3, 2009-12-4 etc., behaves differently in JDK 6 - it throws an IllegalArgumentException saying that the timestamp is not properly formatted. Whereas JDK 5 (and earlier versions) works just fine providing the proper values with '0' prefixed to those single digit numbers.

JDK 6 is just being more strict because the method does expect it's argument to be a String in JDBC timestamp escape format. However, this BREAKS code written in JDK 5.

Code like:

```
String s = "2009-9-1 00:00:00";
Timestamp t = Timestamp.valueOf(s);
```

However JDK 6 is fine with hours, minutes, seconds being single digits. I have figured out what's wrong by looking at the source code of Timestamp class in JDK 6. I found an array intDate[] which is initialized to {4,2,2} and the length of each item in the date is checked against this array.

Now why did the time part work fine even when there are single digits in them? Because the code that checks the length against an equivalent array intTime[] is commented out in source.

The Timestamp class in JDK 5 did not have any of these checks and work just fine with such inputs.

I do not find such oddities mentioned anywhere in the official site. Though I found one other person having the [same problem](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5339666). This problem is easily fixable and I am interested in finding out other such odd changes that had happened in JDK 6.

Comment: what makes you think there are any?

Comment: I recently found one in the way Timestamp.valueOf() works. I will add the details in the question.

Comment: @Geo, I don't agree. I think a serious real list of changes that change behavior can have an objective answer. Admittedly the qualification "major" is subjective, though.

Comment: I'm not convinced this should have been closed. Admittedly the question could be better phrased, but it's addressing a real (non-subjective) issue, isn't it ? Nominated for re-opening.

Comment: Vijay, if you post the issue you had with Timestamp.valueOf you will probably get more votes to reopen.

Comment: @Yishai: Done. I do not understand why people would want to close this question. @Brian: Can you help in rephrasing the question? I have provided more information now.

Comment: FWIW, there is an RFE for the Timestamp.valueOf spec to be more generous http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6763465 . The correction in behaviour was caused by fixing the bug "java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(String) fails to throw an IllegalArgumentException" http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=5006540 So really this is a gotcha of JDK5 (and earlier).

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: If you put this as an answer, I would accept it! Thanks for the find.

Comment: @Vijay: If you would've asked: *What causes the problem with `Timestamp.valueOf()` etc etc* in first place, I bet Tom Hawtin would've posted that as an answer already.

Comment: @Oscar: hmm.. makes sense. However, I was looking at more such issues and hence the question about gotchas. You guys are of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Officially, [this](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/compatibility.html#incompatibilities)

**EDIT**

Additionally you can take a look at Sun's bug database.

This [link](http://bugs.sun.com/search.do?process=1&category=java&bugStatus=3&subcategory=&type=bug&keyword=1.6+1.5) shows items in Java of type bug with status accepted and the keywords "1.6 1.5"

I check a few of them and it looks like what you need.

Comment: @Oscar: I have given an example where JDK 6 behaves in an unexpected manner. I have seen the list of incompatibilities in the official site before posting the question here, though I did not find it much useful.

Comment: Also of note was the Mustang Regression Challenge (I believe all the issues mentioned were fixed before the First Customer Ship). https://mustang.dev.java.net/regchal/

Comment: @Vijay Dev: I didn't knew you've checked the list before posting ( you didn't mentioned that in the original question ) I don't know either if you have already look into the Sun's bug database. Here's the link http://bit.ly/3ZohZ5

Comment: @Oscar: True, I did not mention that in the question. The bug database however looks like what I was looking for. Thanks! Will look into it.

Comment: @Oscar: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6763465 (mentioned by @Tom Hawtin in the comments to the question) in the bug database contains information about the behaviour of Timestamp.valueOf(). Thanks again!